# getMultiAdapter fails with ComponentLookupError

Tags: plone, zope, z3c.form, zope.interface, zope.component

I have a code that looks up an iterface with get multi adapter. One of the element's members that get passed to multi adapter is providing that interface but not the element itself.

I have no control about what gets passed to multi adapter but I have control over the element that contains one of the elements in it. How do I mark it? to notify multi-adapter that there's something in there that could be useful, is there something like ***provideAdapterFactory(cls, interface)***?

Code example:

declarations

```
class ImplementsInterface(object):
    implements(IMarker)

class Parent(object)
    child = ImplementsInterface()
```

lookup

```
some_members = zope.component.getMultiAdapter(((Parent()), IMarker)
```

Now, if I run the code like this, it will produce ***ComponentLookupError***, at the same time I cannot modify lookup code or for multi adapter or for that matter I cannot assign 'implements(IMarker) to Parent because parent already implements a different interface and will break lots of other things.

Update:

I think I've found an explanation that I can makes sense out of [Chapter 6.1 Multi Adapter](http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html)

Update 2:
I think I'm not initializing zca correctly in my unit testing code, here's a snippet

```
import unittest2 as unittest
from zope.traversing.adapters import DefaultTraversable
from z3c.form.testing import TestRequest
from z3c.form import testing, field
from zope import component


class TestFunctionalForm(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        testing.setUp(self)
        component.provideAdapter(field.FieldWidgets)
        component.provideAdapter(DefaultTraversable, [None])
        self.context = self.globs['root']
    def tearDown(self):
        testing.tearDown(self)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve actually.

Comment: Why you cannot assign implements(IMarker) to parent? Classes support multiple interfaces.

Comment: I'm writing a z3c widget and I'm trying to mock test with form.AddForm. Now I'm getting ComponentLookupError on z3c.form.interfaces.IAction https://github.com/avolkov/z3c.widget.optchoice/commit/19574d9d0673cf2d37e67839f6645357ca0eb545

Comment: I stepped through the code with Imarker.providedBy and everything should work. I think I'm not initializing zca properly